# iOS LifeCycle methods not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

So I'm debugging some code I didn't write. It's quite complex, and I'm trying to get a handle on the bug I'm tracking down. But, for some reason, on our login page, none of the lifecycle methods are firing.

I've placed breakpoints on them, put console logs there, and no matter what, everything points to them not firing.

Why would methods such as `viewDidLoad:` and `viewWillAppear:` etc. not fire? Are there any times that could happen? Or any times it could skip a breakpoint or console line in those methods?

Sorry if these are dumb questions, I'm just super perplexed as to how a VC on screen doesn't call these methods but still is on screen? I've used chisel to confirm that the code I'm looking at is indeed for the VC on screen, and it is. So I'm at a complete loss. I would be VERY grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you try posting some code?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct controller. If you have to run breakpoints up to where the controller gets presented.

Comment: If they're not firing, then the view controller's view isn't being added to the view hierarchy. Have you verified that your program is actually creating an instance of the view controller at all? How is the program supposed to create an instance of the view controller?

Comment: I use Chisel and the pvc command to print the recursive hierarchy of view controllers out, and the login page is on the stack and in the window, so it is being instantiated I would guess. I can try to find some code to post that may help, I'm still digging around trying to figure out how its actually presented to see what I may be missing in it.

Comment: Edit your question to include the pvc output, and explain which part is the problematic view controller. Also, explain how the view controller is created: from a storyboard, or by creating it in code?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues before and it was due to duplicate copy of container in the simulator.You can try resetting your simulator, clean the build and check once again.